# Having trouble with this Koan - solved it, but I don't think what I wrote is correct in regards to Typing

Tags: typescript

I'm working through these Koans: https://github.com/paytonrules/typescript.koans#readme

I'm on file 3, collections, the very first function `foreach`:

```
export interface Dictionary<T> {
  [index: string]: T;
}

interface ArrayForEachIteratee<T> {
  (value?: T, index?: number, collection?: Array<T>): any;
}

interface DictionaryForEachIteratee<T> {
  (value?: T, key?: string, collection?: Dictionary<T>): any;
}

/**
 * ### forEach
 * should iterate over all items of array or all properties of an object
 *
 * ## Examples
 *
 *  let collection = ["first", "second", "third"];
 *  let result = [];
 *  let iteratee = (value, index, collection) => result[index] = [index, value];
 *
 *  _.forEach(collection, iteratee); => result === [[0, 'first'], [1, 'second'], [2, 'thidrd']];
 *
 *  collection = {
 *    "0": "first",
 *    "1": "second",
 *    "2": "third"
 *  };
 *  result = [];
 *  iteratee = (value, index, collection) => result[index] = [index, value];
 *
 *  _.forEach(collection, iteratee); => result === [['0', 'first'], ['1', 'second'], ['2', 'thidrd']];
 *
 */
export function forEach() {
}
```

When I look at the test code, I can see that the first test sends it an array and a function, and the second test sends it a dictionary and a function:

```
describe("forEach", function () {
    context("when collection is an array", function () {
      it("should iterate over all items of array", function () {
        const collection = ["first", "second", "third"];
        const iteratee = sinon.spy();
        _.forEach(collection, iteratee);
        sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(iteratee, "first", 0, collection);
        sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(iteratee, "second", 1, collection);
        sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(iteratee, "third", 2, collection);
      });
    });

    context("when collection is an object", function () {
      it("should iterate over all items of object", function () {
        const collection: _.Dictionary<string> = {
          "0": "first",
          "1": "second",
          "2": "third"
        };
        const iteratee = sinon.spy();
        _.forEach(collection, iteratee);
        sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(iteratee, "first", "0", collection);
        sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(iteratee, "second", "1", collection);
        sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(iteratee, "third", "2", collection);
      });
    });
  });
```

So I set up my code to accept an array or a dictionary, and the corresponding array / dictionary callback for the second argument:

```
export function forEach<T>(collection: Array<T> | Dictionary<T>, iteratee: ArrayForEachIteratee<T> | DictionaryForEachIteratee<T>): void {
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    collection.forEach(iteratee);
  } else {
    Object.keys(collection)
        .forEach(key => {
          const value = collection[key];
          iteratee(value, key, collection);
        });
  }  
}
```

My code passes the tests - I'm passing the right arguments to the right functions in the right ways - but I'm absolutely certain that I'm not doing it in the proper Typescript-y type-safe way. My editor is showing me lots of red.

Can I get some pointers on how an expert typescripter would gracefully handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Compilation errors

Here is the reason is why you got compilation errors. Compiler doesn't understands that if `collection` is `Array<T>`, then `iteratee` is `ArrayForEachIteratee<T>`.

We should help compiler to realize that. Unfortunately, it seems it's impossible to build such instruction to typescript without significant rework of code.

So instead we can leverage type-casting:

```
if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    collection.forEach(iteratee as ArrayForEachIteratee<T>);
    return;
} 

Object.keys(collection)
    .forEach(key => {
        const value = collection[key];
        (iteratee as DictionaryForEachIteratee<T>)(value, key, collection);
    });
```

But this doesn't looks pretty.
In typescript there are [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions). Let's build one, but without actual checks on type (because we don't need them & we can't perform then):

```
function forceTypeNarrow<TWanted>(value: any): asserts value is TWanted {}
```

Now if we will put `forceTypeNarrow` somewhere in code, then all next lines in scope will think that `value` has type `TWanted`.

Now we can rewrite contents of our `forEach` function:

```
if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    forceTypeNarrow<ArrayForEachIteratee<T>>(iteratee);
    collection.forEach(iteratee);
    return;
} 

Object.keys(collection)
    .forEach(key => {
        const value = collection[key];
        forceTypeNarrow<DictionaryForEachIteratee<T>>(iteratee);
        iteratee(value, key, collection);
    });
```

## Proper function declaration

Let's take a look on your function declaration

```
export function forEach<T>(collection: Array<T> | Dictionary<T>, iteratee: ArrayForEachIteratee<T> | DictionaryForEachIteratee<T>): void {
```

This declaration allows user-code to pass `(collection: Array<T>, iteratee: DictionaryForEachIteratee<T>)`. But we don't want to allow that!

Let's leverage [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads). We will put one overload for `Array<T>`, second overload for `Dictionary<T>`. And typescript forces us to put third non-end-user-code overload for internal purposes.

```
export function forEach<T>(
    collection: Array<T>, 
    iteratee: ArrayForEachIteratee<T>
): void;
export function forEach<T>(
    collection: Dictionary<T>, 
    iteratee: DictionaryForEachIteratee<T>
): void;
export function forEach<T>(
    collection: Array<T> | Dictionary<T>, 
    iteratee: ArrayForEachIteratee<T> | DictionaryForEachIteratee<T>
): void {
   …
}
```

### Proper formatting of header

Long lines are not good, because they force everyone to use scroll (in IDE, in PR or here on codereview).

In case if your function header is too long, you should put each parameter on new-line. That will make your code readable.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have a questino about your Overload area - is there a reason for the last specification? `collection: Array<T> | Dictionary<T>, 
    iteratee: ArrayForEachIteratee<T> | DictionaryForEachIteratee<T>` -- aren't all the possibilities covered by the previous two specifications?

Comment: my system isn't liking the forceTypeNarrow definition...

Comment: > aren't all the possibilities covered by the previous two specifications?.
Well, yeah, they covered. But typescript is a bit "stupid" and can't merge them automatically. Typescript forces you to specify merged version as last specification. 
The first and second declaration is called the overload signature. The last declaration is called the implementation signature (and this signature can't be called directly).

I don't know why typescript compiler forces us to write an implementation signature. Maybe for clarity.

Comment: If your system doesn't like forceTypeNarrow, then probably the issue is that your typescript is before v3.7.5. Try to update it. 
It works perfectly in typescript playground, see https://shorturl.at/dCQ03

Comment: thanks, this all was extremely helpful! thank you! I couldn't find any of this `forceTypeNarrow` function online -- do you know if a similar pattern is commonly used by a different name?

Comment: No, sorry. I just invented it for sake of clarity and never seen it before

Comment: Hey, one more question: `forceTypeNarrow<ArrayForEachIteratee<T>>(iteratee);` vs `iteratee = iteratee as <ArrayForEachIteratee<T>` -- is there any reason to prefer one over the other in your opinion?

Comment: @TKoL your code (i = i as T) will not change type of variable i. In order to change type you need to introduce new variable (i2 = i as T). I think, there are no strict preference except beauty/ugly (and it's up to you)

Comment: "your code (i = i as T) will not change type of variable i" -- my editor seems to think it works, and it compiles okay.

Comment: @TKoL wow, I was wrong.

Comment: @TKoL okay, in such case it seems that forceTypeNarrow is redundant, because u can achieve that by "normal" way

Comment: ty for considering it, and for your advice

Comment: @TKoL recently I found that trick `i = i as T` doesn't works for `const` variables. I also found that this trick doesn't work when `i` is `any` or `unknown`. So it seems, that there are cases for `forceTypeNarrow`